I'm using this memoized dropdown component, which seems to close due to a re-render when the child text input box component inside changes
I'm stuck on this problem where I memoized the Dropdown component because it was causing infinite re-renders when I selected something from the dropdown. Now I'm facing an issue where everytime I enter something in the search field, the dropdown closes before I can see the search results. I researched and found out it's because I should've declared the memoized component outside of the function component SelectCategory. But now I find that when I move it outside of the function component, it faces the infinite re-render loop again. What am I missing?
import React, { memo, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { categoryName } from '@/types/fruits'
import DropdownMenu from '@/components/shared/dropdowns/DropdownMenu'
import DropdownMenuItem from '@/components/shared/dropdowns/DropdownMenuItem'
import IconButton from '@/components/shared/buttons/IconButton'
import { IoMdMore } from 'react-icons/io'
import TextInputField from '@/components/shared/forms/TextInputField'
import { BiSearch } from 'react-icons/bi'
import { Fruits } from '@/types/fruits/fruits'
import { useSelectedFruitStore } from '@/stores/fruits/useSelectedFruitCategoryStore'

type SelectCategoryProps = {
  fruit: Fruits
}

export default function SelectCategory(props: SelectCategoryProps) {
//for tracking search input
  const [searchCategoryText, setSearchCategoryText] = useState('')

  //for tracking the entire list of selected category for fruits
const { selectedFruitCategory, onSelectCategory } = useSelectedFruitCategoryStore()

  const onSelectCategoryChange = (value: string) => {
    if (value !== searchCategoryText) setSearchCategoryText(value)
  }

//here i sort through the list of selected fruits to find the fruit passed as prop so i can display the category 
  const selectedCategoryForFruit = selectedFruitCategory.find(category => category.id === props.fruit._id)

//here i generate the list of categories from a const variable list of categories and render the dropdown items
//note : this also depends on the state variable since dropdown items change when a new search is entered
const generateCategoryTypeOptionList = () => {
    return Object.entries(categoryName)
      .filter(([key, value]) => value.toLowerCase().includes(searchCategoryText.toLowerCase()))
      .map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
          <DropdownMenuItem
            key={key}
            label={value}
            onClick={() => {
              if (selectedCategoryForFruit?.label === value) {
                return
              }

              onSelectCategory({
                fruitId: props.fruit._id,
                label: value,
                category: key as keyof typeof categoryName,
              })
            }}
          />
        )
      })
  }

  const menuList = generateCategoryTypeOptionList()

  const MemorizedMenu = memo(DropdownMenu)

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
      <MemorizedMenu
        items={menuList}
        renderHeader={() => (
          <div className="sticky top-0 bg-white">
            <TextInputField
              icon={<BiSearch color="gray" size={20} />}
              className="p-3 w-full"
              placeholder="Search..."
              inputClasses="bg-custom-gray"
              onTextChange={onSelectCategoryChange}
              size="sm"
            />
          </div>
        )}
      >
        <IconButton className="border-1 border-slate-200" icon={<IoMdMore size={18} />} />
      </MemorizedMenu>
    </div>
  )
}

I tried moving the useState in a separate zustand (even though I know that is not how stores should be used), memoizing ALL the props, moving the memoized declaration outside of function component, exporting a memoized version of the component but nothing changed. Either the search works or the re-render issue is fixed.
